# ActiveMQ startup problem on Windows - FileNotFoundException for jolokia-access.xml

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I downloaded and unzipped the latest ActiveMQ version 5.17.1. I'm using Java 11.0.11 and Windows 10 Enterprise Build: 19044.1706.

When I started ActiveMQ via `.\bin\activemq.bat start` I got this `FileNotFoundException`:

```
WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: C:\Programs\apache-activemq-5.17.1\bin\..\data\kahadb only has 21729 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 21729 mb
WARN | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: C:\Programs\apache-activemq-5.17.1\bin\..\data only has 21728 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 21728 mb
INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://127.0.0.1:8161/
INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://127.0.0.1:8161/api/jolokia/
WARN | jolokia-agent: Error while accessing access restrictor at file:C:Programsapache-activemq-5.17.1bin..conf/jolokia-access.xml. Denying all access to MBeans for security reasons. Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:Programsapache-activemq-5.17.1bin..conf\jolokia-access.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:Programsapache-activemq-5.17.1bin..conf\jolokia-access.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219) ~[?:?]
       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[?:?]
       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112) ~[?:?]
```

How do I fix this `FileNotFoundException`?

It seems to be some problem with the file names (i.e. `C:Programsapache-activemq-5.17.1bin..conf\jolokia-access.xml`).

I am not even sure if I should trust the `FileNotFoundException` error message.

Comment: I doubt, that the file `C:Programsapache-activemq-5.17.1bin..conf\jolokia-access.xml` actually exists. Something stripped the path separators aways, it seems.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes, I think it's some problem in the start up batch file on Windows. Something related to this line: `set DEFAULT_ACTIVEMQ_HOME=%~dp0..`

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug. I think you should [report it to ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/issues).

Comment: @JustinBertram I see you work on ActiveMQ, could you report it for me? I need to create JIRA account etc. etc. Too complicated for filing a single bug.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8628

Answer (score 4):

When I set a Windows environment variable

`ACTIVEMQ_HOME=C:/Programs/apache-activemq-5.17.1/`

I am able to solve the problem (note the trailing slash).
The error disappears then.

But I noticed a few more things:

1. If I set the variable to `ACTIVEMQ_HOME=C:/Programs/apache-activemq-5.17.1` I still have that problem.
2. If I set `ACTIVEMQ_HOME=C:\Programs\apache-activemq-5.17.1\` I still have the problem (i.e. if I use backslashes).
3. If I don't have a Windows environment variable `ACTIVEMQ_HOME` defined at all, I also have the problem.

So this seems like a bug in the ActiveMQ Windows startup script `activemq.bat`. It should not be so sensitive to this value. Also it should work without `ACTIVEMQ_HOME` being set at all (but it doesn't work).

Answer (score 3):

I kind of agree this needs to be fixed from ActiveMq side.
But to resolve this issue you can set Environment Variable as -

```
ACTIVEMQ_HOME=C:\\Programs\\apache-activemq-5.17.1\\
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Based on input in the [Active MQ Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8596), I replaced ${prop:activemq.conf} with the following in the D:\Program Files\activemq\webapps\api\WEB-INF\web.xml

```
    <init-param>
    <param-name>policyLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:D:/Program Files/activemq/conf/jolokia-access.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Afterwhich, the error is not thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the apache-activemq-5.17.4\bin\win64\wrapper.conf
Approximately line 64

Under The Java Additional Parameters section, enclose the directory variable and filename in quotes:

FROM:

`wrapper.java.additional.13=-Djolokia.conf=file:%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/jolokia-access.xml`

TO:

`wrapper.java.additional.13=-Djolokia.conf=file:"%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/jolokia-access.xml"`

Answer (score 0):

Setting environment variable ([from OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72575295/1651107)) did not work for me for version 5.17.1.

One easy solution is to use different activeMQ version. For example apache-activemq-5.16.3 works correctly. Here is archive of versions available: https://activemq.apache.org/download-archives

Answer (score 0):

As others reported, this happens because the ACTIVEMQ_HOME is not set.
However, if you create a new broker using the `activeq-admin` script like this

```
.\activemq-admin.bat create ..\standalone\mybroker
```

you can run it with `standalone\mybroker.bat start` and it runs just fine.
If you examine the batch file, you'll see that the environment variable ACTIVEMQ_HOME is set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the wrapper configuration as shown below:

```
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/conf

wrapper.java.additional.13=-Djolokia.conf=classpath:jolokia-access.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed ActiveMQ 5.18.3 as Windows service using the installer script `bin/win64/InstallService.bat`.

Got the error in `activemq.log` when the service starts:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:apache-activemq-5.18.3binwin64....\conf\jolokia-access.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

My solution was to change `bin/win64/wrapper.conf` and set an absolute path like:

```
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Djolokia.conf=file:"C:/apache-activemq-5.18.3/conf/jolokia-access.xml"
```

The whole problem for Windows service installation results from the above mentioned installer script. `ACTIVEMQ_BASE` is defined at service installation time and I think this is the root cause why you can't change it later easily.